# NG-zorro, problem with iteration of Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to ask you why I have trouble getting my observable in the [nzData], but not if I get the data in the * nfIF. In detail with this approac works good:

```
<div *ngIf="visibleAggregate">
  <nz-table
    id="activitiesTable"
    *ngIf="tableData$ | async as Table"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of Table.columns">
          {{ column.label }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   
  </nz-table>
</div>
```

But if I pass my observable to the nzData it tells me it's not iterable. I need to pass data to nzData. ([nzData]="tableData$ | async")

I create the observable in this way

```
 private groupBySubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private groupBy$ = this.groupBySubject.asObservable();
  tableData$: Observable<TableData> = combineLatest([
    this.database$,
    this.groupBy$,
  ]).pipe(map(([db, sc]) => this.buildTableData(db, sc)));

  group(value: Observable<any>) {
    this.groupBySubject.next(value);
  }
```

error:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: listOfData is not iterable
    at MapSubscriber.project (ng-zorro-antd-table.js:1742)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:73)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
    at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (combineLatest.js:52)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:61)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
```

I would just like to do:

```
<div *ngIf="visibleAggregate">
  <nz-table
    #aggregate
    id="activitiesTable"
    [nzData]="tableData$ | async"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of aggregate.data">
          {{ column.columns.label }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </nz-table>
</div>
```

I have used this approach with other Obserables and it works, even from documentation.
I don't understand why with this obserable it works only in the first mode shown.

Comment: should have written the error too.

Comment: ok sorry, done!

Answer (score 0):

`[nzData]="tableData$ | async"` will work if `tableData$` is `BehavourSubject` and you initially provide it a default value.

Here async only means that it will update and return to nzData that the value inside the observable.
Without the async you are passing `arr: any[] = new  Subject()` but `new Subject()` is not an array or iterable.

```
*ngIf=" only checked if the statement here is true or false "
```

since `tableData$` is not undefined, it will return true due to the subject, not the value it will provide in observable.

```
\\ initialize with  empty array so its always have a value
    tableData$ = new BehaviorSubject<Table[]>([]) 
    
     combineLatest([
        this.database$,
        this.groupBy$,
      ]).subscribe(([db, sc]) => this.tableData$.next(this.buildTableData(db, sc)));
```

Comment: I need to do [nzData] = "tableData $ | async" without using ngIf to get the data.

Comment: can you update your question where yo have used nzData, i don't see it being used

Comment: Read my answer, tableData$  needs to be behaviorSubject, it doe snot have an initialised value of BehavourSubject([]).

Comment: tableData$ = new BehaviorSubject<Table>([])

 combineLatest([
    this.database$,
    this.groupBy$,
  ]).subscribe(([db, sc]) => this.tableData$.next(this.buildTableData(db, sc)));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236671/discussion-between-vaira-and-man24).